# Is there a good physical model for what happens when a light bulb suddenly goes out?

Tags: current, failure, pulse, reliability, modeling

Sometimes a light bulb just stops working and goes dark for seemingly no reason. Can  Dirac δ impulse to a light bulb serve as a mathematical model for what happens so we can assume that the electric current for the light bulb or the component itself had a sudden spike that caused the light bulb to go dark? Is there some other good explanation or should we assume that the component fails randomly in time according to a Poisson distribution if we want to model electronic circuitry's reason for failing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Incandescent bulbs fail because the filament wears out and gets too thin, and then breaks. DC filaments also suffer from uneven wear called "notching".

Since the filament gets thin and brittle over time, it tends to fail when mechanically shocked ( for example at turn-on when the resistance is low).

There is a distribution of lifetime that is an exponential function of filament voltage. You can find models in some of the old GE literature if you look. [Here's another article](http://www.iesna.org/PDF/100Papers/050.pdf) which covers some aspects of your question.

Comment: Worth mentioning that the thinnest part of the filament is the hottest, which is where it wears out the fastest, causing that part to heat up more, and so on.

Comment: @Mark also that the wearing out is transfer of material from the filament to elsewhere in the bulb- which is why old bulbs look darker inside than fresh bulbs when off.