# Voltage in a fluorescent light bulb?

Tags: current, failure, fluorescent-lamp

This is sort of a spin off of [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/130873/is-there-a-good-physical-model-for-what-happens-when-a-light-bulb-suddenly-goes).  Fluorscent have a tiny transformer inside them, and a bunch of capacitors, as well as transistors, and diodes.  What exactly happens when a light bulb goes out?  Is it the transformers fault?

Comment: What has your research shown? This will be well documented elsewhere without the need for someone to write an essay for you here.

Comment: e.g. http://www.electronicspoint.com/threads/re-failure-modes-for-fluorescent-lamps.190047/

Comment: @Transistor There are a lot of reasons but not an in-depth explanation on the sites I went.

Comment: Do you mean Compact Fluorescent Lamps (CFL´s), as apposed to the 'classic' fluorescent strip light? As you note, CFL's are a lot more complicated and have several components in them that could fail. Your question is really too general to answer. Do you have any personal examples?

Comment: @F.Bloggs I am generally talking about the small light bulbs used to light a person's house.

Comment: Ok. I think you have your answer below. The small lamps have several components that could fail due to quality control issues, etc. As I said, do you have any examples, or just asking a general question?

Comment: @Sigma6RPU you seem to have accepted a fairly short overview answer. Are you actually after an in-depth explanation?

Comment: @user2943160 Yes because I checked out the light bulb, and that is what happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal aging process results from inert gas contamination from electrode wear which causes current to increase above a shutdown threshold to prevent excess power dissipation.

Most of the aging occurs during cold start if cycled many times per day in 4' linear tubes rated for 30khr which can last 50khr  if left on all the time.

Small embedded CFL lamp failures are subject to design variations and process quality and may fail from active ballast failures.